# disable all click synthesis events of react

Tags: reactjs, events, click

I have a problem with React. In my case, I add an event listener to document, in listener I want to disable all click synthesis events of react

https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-hill-hxu3o?file=/public/index.html

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code, this will help,

*Tested in codesandbox*

```html
<!-- index.html -->
document.addEventListener(
"click", (e) => {
  console.log("document hop H1 click not exec");
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  },
true
);
```

Here is the source [link:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: it's work for me, thanks

Comment: can you please accept my answer, if it works as expected, that will help other developers as well. @步行街

Comment: If am adding this in index.jsx of react, and i if clicked in any child component , will this be fired and stop the child component onClick function?